# PrestaShop module structure incorrect

Tags: validation, config, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, add-on

[image]

PrestaShop extension shop is throwing popup box when uploading compressed module. Done code cleanup over http://validator.prestashop.com what noticed me about:

[image]

[image]

although it was created over module generator.

```
   <displayName><![CDATA[dosje.in]]></displayName>

   <version><![CDATA[1.0.1]]></version>

   <description><![CDATA[dosje.in basic data integration.]]</description>
```

Comment: So did you correct these issues? What is it saying now?

Comment: Do you compress the whole folder or only the content? The first folder of the zip should be the folder of your module.

Comment: @JulienLachal - it is not clear for me , why it throws this display name error, because as far as I know , it fits requests

displayName : name of 6 symbols
description : text by 70  symbols. Initially generated with Module generator inside the http://validator.prestashop.com.

Comment: And what's inside the config.xml of your module? Can your update your question with its content pls?

Comment: ```<displayName><![CDATA[dosje.in]]></displayName>

<version><![CDATA[1.0.1]]></version>

<description><![CDATA[dosje.in basic data integration.]]</description>```